# ¿Es posible hacer más simple esta secuencia de Fibonacci en Python? (usando loops)

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, bucles

Estoy repasando algunos conceptos básicos de Python y realizando ejercicios al respecto. Uno de ellos es realizar una secuencia de Fibonacci, que resolví empleando un `while` y un par de operadores `+=`. Mi pregunta es si este código puede hacerse más sencillo usando `loops`.

```
a=1
b=1

print(a)
print(b)
while True:
    a+=b
    b+=a
    if b>1000:
        break
    print(a)
    print(b)


Salida:

1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
```

Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Como lo tienes ahora estás generando los números de dos en dos. Una forma de hacerlo más simple sería generarlos uno a uno y usar asignación de tuplas:

```
a = b = 1
while a <= 1000:
    print(a)
    (a,b) = (b,a+b)
```

Comment: Nunca se me hubiera ocurrido esa solución. Es totalmente "pythonic". ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes pedir también la cantidad de valores y usar for loop:

```
num=int(input('Cuántos valores de la sucesión de Fibonacci deseas?: ' ))
a, b=0,1
for i in range (num):
    print(a, end=' ' )
    a, b=b, a+b
```

En este caso, mediante input se pide al usuario que introduzca la cantidad de valores de la sucesión que desea generar. El valor introducido por el usuario se almacena en una variable que en este caso le he puesto "num". int permite procesar este valor como entero. Se establecen dos variables "a" y "b" con valor inicial de 0 y 1 respectivamente, que permitirán calcular los siguientes valores de la sucesión. El "for" permite repetir el cálculo hasta que llega al valor de "num", que es la cantidad de valores de la sucesión que desea el usuario. En este caso "a" representa el nuevo valor calculado de la sucesión y se obtiene como la suma de "b" y el valor anterior de "a", es decir suma los dos valores anteriores de la sucesión para obtener el nuevo valor. Se imprime en pantalla el nuevo valor de a en cada recorrido del "for" y mediante el comando "end=" " se muestran horizontalmente.
En la última linea se utiliza la asignación paralela de Python:
a, b = b, a+b
Que equivale a decir:
a=b
b=a+b
Pero tiene la ventaja de que conserva el valor anterior de a, de lo contrario se perdería con la asignación simple. También puedes usar tres variables para hacer que funcione sin la asignación paralela, por ejemplo:

```
    num=int(input('Cuántos valores de la sucesión de Fibonacci deseas?: ' ))
    a=0
    b=1
    c=1
    print ('0 \n1' ) 
    for i in range (num) 
          print (c) 
          a=b
          b=c
          c=a+b
```

Por otra parte también se puede usar una solución más matemática empleando listas de python:

```
    num=int(input('Cuántos valores de la sucesión de Fibonacci deseas?: ' ))
    lista= [0,1] 
    for i in range (2, num):
          b= lista[i-1] +lista[i-2] 
          lista.append (b)
    print(lista)
```

Igualmente se debe notar que la sucesión de Fibonacci debe empezar en 0,  1.

Comment: Por favor explica lo que hace tu codigo

Comment: Hola Christian, lo he detallado sobre el propio post.

Comment: No se debe utilizar `eval`. De hecho, `eval` no evalua expresiones numéricas... evalúa ***código python***. Si en vez de poner un número el usuario introduce el código python necesario para borrarte el disco duro, tu código lo ejecutará! Los casteos de input a entero se hacen con `int()`, es decir -> `int(input("blablabla:"))`

Comment: @EddySL ok, haz los cambios ya que lo que dice Benito B es cierto

Comment: He reemplazado eval por int. También he fusionado ambas respuestas en una. Gracias por los comentarios. Siempre se aprende!